# open a view in new browser window using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
     $(".reportCategoryClass").click(function (i) {
                   var reportUrl;
                   reportUrl = "http://bi.mylcchonda.com/UMAP_BI_REPORTS_PROD";
                    window.open("/LLCReportRoute/LLCReportsPopUp?url=" + reportUrl);
                    // window.open("/ControllerName/ActionName?url=" + reportUrl);
                }
});
```

window.open function opening window but in that page not found error is coming

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's happening on the controller?  Is you action getting called?  If so, what is the value of the url parameter?

Comment: it is not going to controller

Answer (score 0):

is the LLCReportRoute in the root of the site? As you are using an absolute reference there, that may be your problem. To make it relative, remove the "/" at the start.

Comment: LLCReportRoute is controller name,iam sending url string to the view as viewbag

Answer (score 0):

This was becouse of the reportUrl. You need to encode it. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".reportCategoryClass").click(function () {
                       var reportUrl;
                       reportUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://bi.mylcchonda.com/UMAP_BI_REPORTS_PROD");
                        window.open("/LLCReportRoute/LLCReportsPopUp?url=" + reportUrl);

    });
});
```

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I don't see there is one extra "}" and I also add document ready for this.